# How do I insert a limited number records to TableA from TableB , where TableC contains the list of records to insert?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.6

The field "contract" is unique in all three tables.

Here is what I got so far

Database setup:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Active_Orders (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
contract VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)  ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO Active_Orders(name, contract)
VALUES ('steve', '3454'),
       ('tom', '6756'),
       ('becky', '9809');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Old_Orders (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
contract VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)  ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO Old_Orders(name,contract)
VALUES ('mark', '9896'),
       ('kelly', '0897'),
       ('paul', '1537'),
       ('will', '8254');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Move_Orders (
contract VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)  ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO Move_Orders(contract)
VALUES ('0897'),
       ('1537);
```

The Code I am using is:

```
INSERT INTO Active_Orders (name, contract)  
SELECT name, contract
FROM Old_Orders
WHERE Move_Orders.contract = Old_Orders.contract;
```

But I am getting

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'Move_Orders.contract' in 'where clause'
```

What I want is:

```
SELECT * FROM Active_Orders;

id  name    contract
1   steve   3454
2   tom     6756
3   becky   9809
4   kelly   0897
5   paul    1537
```

Note:

```
 TableA is Active_Orders
 TableB is Old_Orders
 TableC is Move_Orders
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.  MySQL doesn't know what is `TableC`.

Comment: `TableA`, `TableB`, `TableC` is not a good name to use.  Without you explaining the relationship between those tables, how do you expect us to help you???  If you have a meaningful name like `Order`, `OrderDetail`, `Customer`, then you can omit the explanation.

Comment: *MySQL doesn't know what is `TableC`.* More precisely - `TableC` is not listed in FROM clause.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "join".

Comment: Please give your table structures as DDL (`CREATE TABLE foo (...);`) and your data as DML (`INSERT INTO foo VALUES (...);`) - or better yet, as a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=9c2b9f6caaaaf3d88b1cd86fe314c18c)! Also, please **always** include your version of MySQL - it can be critical for answers as they've introduced a lot of important functionality in the last while. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the following could help:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (name, contract)  
SELECT name, contract
  FROM TableB
 WHERE contract IN (SELECT contract from TableC)
```

P.S. Your query is actually incorrect, TableC is not listed in WHERE clause and thus is unknown in the current context